# Firebase web auth via Google SSO - How to know whether a user registered or logged in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to detect whether the user has just registered via SSO or simply logged in.

The documentation wasn't helpful.

I'm using React + ES6. Here's my current auth method:

```
authWithGoogle = () => {
    this.props.setIsLoggingInState(true);
    firebaseApp
      .auth()
      .getRedirectResult()
      .catch(() => console.error('something went wrong with Google SSO'));
    firebaseApp
      .auth()
      .signInWithRedirect(googleProvider)
      .catch(() => console.error('something went wrong with Google SSO'));
};
```

To be honest, the code above doesn't seem right... (but it works)

Comment: I'm not currently storing the user data in the Realtime Database, and it feels a bit hacky to use that as the means of determining whether the user has already registered...

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
firebaseApp.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(userCredential) {
  // True if the user is new, false if existing.
  console.log(userCredential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser);
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Error occurred.
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The console.log is called before the user even leaves the page (and we have no idea what account they're going to use) and then it's not called again after they actually log in.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the persisted console log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/phsdnp3vir55kj6/Screenshot%202018-08-08%2020.17.39.png?dl=0

Comment: Obviously you are calling it before you sign in. You can only tell if a user is new or existing after they sign in with the OAuth provider.

Comment: Those two sentences seem to say the exact opposite things. I’m confused.

Comment: You first call `signInWithRedirect()`. When you return back to the page and the user is successfully signed in, you call `getRedirectResult()`. This will resolve with a `UserCredential` which will contain additional user info such as whether a user is new (first time to sign) or existing (previously signed in).